# Does God Punish Other People for another's sins?

Tags: sin

In our day and age, according to Judaism, do we believe that others get punished for the sins another commit?

Comment: Please clarify "why our day and age" matters for the question?

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/127172/how-should-a-jewish-person-respond-to-antisemitism/127174#127174

Comment: Devarim 24:16;  “every man shall be put to death for his own sin” - Sifrei Devarim 280:1.

Comment: Also related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/109484/27180

Comment: Idk why the “this day and age” makes a difference but yeah there are cases where we get punished for others sins. Lashon Hara (just listening to it gives you the sin). There’s also the law that you must stop a fellow Jew from sinning, so if you don’t stop him you get his sin

Comment: See Ezekiel 18.

Comment: @CuriousYid Those aren't cases where one gets punished for the sins of others, the person is himself violating a sin. It is its' own independent sin to listen to Lashon Hara, aid a sinner, etc.

Answer (score 2):

It depends. If they had the ability to protest the sin but did not, yes. Otherwise, no. See Talmud Sanhedrin 27b:

> ולא והכתיב (ויקרא כו, לז) וכשלו איש באחיו איש בעון אחיו מלמד שכולן ערבים זה בזה
> The Gemara asks: And are descendants not punished for the sins of their ancestors unless they adopt their behavior? But isn’t it written: “And they shall stumble one upon another” (Leviticus 26:37)? This verse is homiletically interpreted to mean that the Jewish people shall stumble, one due to the iniquity of another, i.e., they are punished for each other’s sins, which teaches that all Jews are considered guarantors, i.e., responsible, for one another.
> התם שהיה בידם למחות ולא מיחו
> The Gemara answers: There, in the verse in Leviticus, the reference is to a case where others had the ability to protest the sin but they did not protest. Consequently, they are punished for not protesting, regardless of any familial relationship they may have with the sinner.

See also the [Shaarei Teshuva](https://www.sefaria.org/Shaarei_Teshuvah.3.195?vhe=Torat_Emet&lang=bi) by Rabbeinu Yonah

> החלק הו' - מי שיש בידו למחות ואינו מוחה. ואין בפיו תוכחות. ועל מעשה חטאים לא ילטוש עין ולא ישגיח. ולא יהיה להם לאיש מוכיח והנה נצטוינו לבער הרע מקרב עמנו. שנאמר (דברים יג) ובערת הרע מקרבך. ואמרו רבותינו - כל מי שיש בידו למחות באנשי ביתו ואינו מוחה נתפש על אנשי ביתו. יש בידו למחות באנשי עירו ואינו מוחה נתפש על אנשי עירו. יש בידו למחות בכל העולם ואינו מוחה נתפש על כל העולם. ונאמר (ויקרא כו) וכשלו איש באחיו ודרשו בו ז"ל איש בעון אחיו ואמרו כל ישראל ערבים זה לזה. ‏
> The sixth section: One who has the ability to protest, but does not protest and has no words of reprimand in his mouth; and does not use the swords of his eyes and does not take responsibility for the deeds of sinners. So he will not be a man of reprimand, whereas we were commanded to destroy the evil from within our nation - as it is stated (Deuteronomy 13:6), “and you shall destroy the evil within you.” And our Rabbis said (Shabbat 54b), “Anyone who is in a position to protest against the members of his household and does not protest, is apprehended for the members of his household; if he is in a position to protest against the people of his city, and does not protest, he is apprehended for the people of his city; if he is in a position to protest the whole world, and does not protest, he is apprehended for the whole world.” And it is stated (Leviticus 26:37), “A man shall stumble over his brother.” And they, may their memory be blessed, expounded (Sanhedrin 27b), “‘A man over’ the iniquity of ‘his brother.’” And they said that all of Israel is responsible for one another.

Comment: Agreed. BUT the person who did not protest is himself guilty of a sin of not protesting against wrong.

Comment: What about children?

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok True. I should have made that clearer.

Comment: @DoubleAA I don't think they are old enough to be punished for not protesting, as Avrohom Yitzchok pointed out.

Comment: So how do you explain בעון נדרים בנים מתים

Comment: @DoubleAA The Rambam says young children can be punished for the sins of their parents. (I'm not sure of the rationale, but I think it is because they are *tafel* to their parent's mazal). But they wouldn't be punished for their own sin of not protesting.

Comment: Seems like a major exception to your answer here

Comment: @DoubleAA I didn't get into it because I don't think I fully understand it.

Answer (score 1):

**Shabbat 33b**

> דאמר רבי גוריון ואיתימא רב יוסף ברבי שמעיה בזמן שהצדיקים בדור
> צדיקים נתפסים על הדור אין צדיקים בדור תינוקות של
> בית רבן
> נתפסים על הדור
>
> For R. Gorion — others state, R. Joseph son of R. Shemaiah — said: When there are righteous men in the generation, the righteous are seized [by death] for the [sins of the] generation; when there are no righteous in a generation, school-children are seized for the generation.
>
> (Soncino translation)

Answer (score 0):

See Chumash Shemos 20:5 and the Gur Aryeh there. See also Shu”t Rashba Hachadashos מכת"י siman 368 who writes the following in the middle of a longer discussion:

> והשנית כי באמת כל חטא פרטי אין עונשו מגיע לכלל אלה אם יצטרף אל הרוב
> ויכריע, והאיש הפרטי שחטא הוא לבדו ישא חטאו, כאמרו בן לא ישא בעון האב
> הנפש החוטאת היא תמות, וחטא בכלל נפרע מן הכלל. ואמנם שלשה דברים שתחשבום
> פרטיים אינם אלא כלליים. הראשון חטא אב המשפחה, והשני חטא המלך, והשלישי
> חטא חטאו עם רב העם שנענשים בו אפילו היחידים שלא הסכימו עמהם בחטא ההוא.
> והטעם בשלשתם מבוארת בכתוב ומצד הכרעת הדעת. חטא חטא בו אב המשפחה, כחטאו
> של אדם הראשון, כי לבדו חטא ואנו מאשימים אותו על כל מה שעשה, ועם כל זה
> נענשו הדורות כלם הבאים אחריו באותן עונשין המפורשין בכתוב המיתה וזיעת
> אפים וצער הלידה וצמיחת קוץ ודרדר, וענש הדורות בנפש לא נכתב ולא נתפרש
> בפרשה זו. וזה ראוי מן הדעת, כי ראש המשפחה שרש לתולדות וכשהשורש נפסד לא
> ימלט הפרי להיותו יונק מאותו הפסד, על כן הבאים ממנו מתדמים לו לעתים
> לאחר כמה דורות בצורתם הגשמית גם בטבעם והנהגתם שטבעם שמור בגזע. והשני
> חטא חטא דוד המלך, כחטאו של דוד במנין העם והגיע העונש לעם, והוא שדוד
> אומר כמתאונן ואלה הצאן מה עשו. וזה ראוי מן הדעת, לפי שאין חזוק המלכות
> לעבור ולעשות כרצונו רק מאשר ימליכוהו בני אדם ונותנים לו רשות לעשות
> כרצונו, ולולא שהם סובלים ממנו ומניחים אותו על חפצו לא היה רשאי לפרוץ
> גדרים גדרתם התורה, ועל כן נתלה חטאו בבנים כאלו הם הסכימו וחטאו עמו.
> והשלישי חטא חטאו בו רוב העם, והוא שאמר הנביא מתאונן כאלו מתאוננין כן
> עדת ישראל על הגלות ועל הצרות, אבותינו חטאו ואינם ואנחנו עונותיהם
> סבלנו. וזה ראוי מן הדעת, לפי שאדם מדיני וצריך כל אחד לקבוץ בני אדם, כי
> לולי זה לא ימצא איש את חפציו, כי יצטרך כל אחד ואחד לתקן צרכיו לחרוש
> ולזרוע ולקצור וכן כל שאר מלאכותיו, ויכלה הזמן ולא יגיע למחצית צרכיו
> שאי אפשר לו זולתם. והרי כלל העם לכל אחד ואחד כאברים לגוף, שכל האברים
> עם היותם מפורדים בתכונת צורתם, זה צריך לזה וזה מרגיש בהגיע התועלת או
> ההפך לאחר, כן העם כלו בכללו כגון גוף אחד, ועל כן היחיד מכריע את הכל
> בין טוב בין להפכו. וכן כשהרבים חוטאים היחידים מרגישים בחטא הרבים
> וסובלים מן הנזק עמהם. ואם כן אפשר שחטאו אז האבות ונענשו הדורות הבאים
> עד זמן ועדן ירצהו  השי"ת. או יש בידינו דברים נעלמים לא נודעו לנו,
> וברוך היודע. והדין דין אמת.

In summary, the Rashba says that only the sinner can bear the punishment of the sin. And, if a group of people sins, they all recieve the brunt of the punishment. However, he gives three examples of instances when it would appear as though one person/group committed a sin, yet others who didn't sin join in bearing the punishment. 1) a father who sins, the family is punished. 2) a king who sins, the nation is punished. 3) a group within a city sins, the whole city is punished, even those who did not take part in the sin. He then says that all three of these make sense logically and also have scriptural support.

I hope this was helpful.

Comment: I assume that some people here are not able to read the Hebrew text.