# Whence "בלי עין הרע"?

Tags: sources-mekorot, words, mysticism-kabbalah, ayin-hara-evil-eye

What is the source, or earliest reference, I guess, of using the phrase, "[בלי עין הרע"](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/27188/5)?

Comment: If you like an answer, consider marking it correct. If not, consider clarifying which additional information you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Rabbi Yissachar Shlomo Teichtal (19th-20th century) uses the expression in משנה שכיר.The expression is also used [here](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=7857&hilite=03a8cb3f-2894-4a55-bf70-761710a71e71&st=%D7%91%D7%9C%D7%99%20%D7%A2%D7%99%D7%9F%20%D7%94%D7%A8%D7%A2) in this earlier 19th century work. My playing around with search engines suggests that the expression arose in the latter half of the 19th century.

Comment: I think it is also mentioned somewhere n Baba Metzia.

Comment: @NS23 you are thinking of 107b.

Comment: Why not address @NS23's comment in your answer?

Comment: @SethJ because as far as I am aware it has no bearing on the OP's question, or on my answer, as it merely mentions ayin hara, not the statement "bli ayin hara", an expression which as I noted does not appear until thousands of years later.