# Meaning of the (Hebrew?) abbreviation Ka"H

Tags: hebrew, language, text, acronyms

I saw this on a frum forum:

> It bothers me when my daughters keep hearing about their **(ka"h)** appearance,and no one talks 
>   about character.

I had never seen this abbreviation before. Does anyone know what it stands for? What it means? How it is used?

Comment: To close voters: This expression is used for Jewish religious reasons. This is not a Hebrew (or Yiddish as it turns out) question. Is it really necessary that the questioner know this before asking? And given that it does, in fact, have something to do with Judaism do we have to close a question for not explicitly stating: Is this abbreviation motivated by Judaism? The question provided enough sourcing for why it would be suspected to be Judaism related.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's a Yiddish abbreviation for ***K***ein **A**yin **H**ora - or in Hebrew *Bli Ayin Hara*.

Simply stated *without the evil eye*; we're not discussing [something] in order to get [it] punished due to our jealousy.

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/27188